# SWRevealViewController panGestureRecognizer with UIScreenEdgeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

I've been looking for solution for this question,but didnt find any one. So I use SWRevealViewController for sidebar menu in my project but I want that side menu would open when user beging to touch from left edge of the view. I want this because I have another swipeGestureRecognizer for left and right swipe.For adding left and right swipes I'm use this code:

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipedToRight:)];
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(swipedToLeft:)];
       swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
```

So my question is how can I make that side menu would open only when touches begins from left edge?

**UPD 1**

I use this code to open side menu by panning at any part of the screen

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer: self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

And I have recognizer to swipe to right. The problem is once it open menu and once executes swipe's action. I want to allow to open menu only when touches is from left edge

**UPD 2 Solved**

I solved it by setting draggable border width:

```
self.revealViewController.draggableBorderWidth = self.view.frame.size.width / 2;
```

And now gesture from edge to center opens menu, and from center to right border executes swipe's action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is modify the already existent pop gesture that is built into the UINavigationController class.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a UIPanGestureRecognizer as you mentioned before or add a subView in the top of your view and add a gesture to it:

```
UIView *topView = ...
[self.view addSubview: topView];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];

[topView addGestureRecognizer:pan];
```

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is modify the already existent pop gesture that is built into the `UINavigationController` class.

Example code to add to your viewWillAppear:

```
if ([self.navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(interactivePopGestureRecognizer)]) {
    self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
    // Your code here
}
```